# Не видит путь к файлу

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.title('Класификатор изображений чисел')
root.geometry('340x340')

las =Label(root, text='Укажите полный путь до файла!')
las.place(x=0, y=10)
e_get = Entry(root)
e_get.place(x=180,y=10)


btn_start =Button(root, text = "Начать")
btn_start.place (x=10,y=34)
btn_start.bind('<Button-1>', lambda even: rage (e_get))
def rage(z):
    x = z
    img = image.load_img(x, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show

# Преобразуем изображением в массив numpy
    x1 = image.img_to_array(img)

# Инвертируем и нормализуем изображение
    x1 = 255 - x1
    x1 /= 255
    x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, axis=0)# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    json_file = open("mnist_model_conv.json", "r")
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    loaded_model.load_weights("mnist_model_conv.h5")

    loaded_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])


    prediction = loaded_model.predict(x1)
    print(np.argmax(prediction))


root.mainloop()
```

Пишу приложение-классификатор, пытаюсь ввести путь к файлу и записать его с последующим использованием в классификаторе, но при вводе выдает ошибку

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2481, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/АНГЕИНА/Desktop/neuron/salo.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    btn_start.bind('<Button-1>', lambda even: rage (e_get))
  File "C:/Users/АНГЕИНА/Desktop/neuron/salo.py", line 21, in rage
    img = image.load_img(x, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 322, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2483, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'read'
```

как я понял он не видит путь к файлу, прошу вас помогите!

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что `fp` - это поле ввода (в которое вы видимо ввели путь), и у него нет методов `seek` и `read`. Вам нужно прочитать из поля ввода текст, потом открыть файл с этим именем, потом уже делать над файлом то что нужно.

Comment: @insolor не подскажите как это сделать??

Comment: Сейчас ответом напишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что `fp` - это поле ввода (в которое вы видимо ввели путь), и у него нет методов `seek` и `read` (буквально `AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'seek'` и `AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'read'` означает: "Ошибка атрибута: у объекта `Entry` нет атрибута `read`", и то же самое с `seek`).

Ошибка возникает внутри сторонней библиотеки, но раз туда попало текстовое поле (объект класса `Entry` из tkinter), значит проблема не в библиотеке, а в том что вы сами туда передали это текстовое поле.

Смотрим по стэктрейсу сверху вниз в каком месте происходит вызов метода из библиотеки. Вот эта строка:

```
  File "C:/Users/АНГЕИНА/Desktop/neuron/salo.py", line 21, in rage
    img = image.load_img(x, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
```

Смотрим окружающий код:

```
btn_start.bind('<Button-1>', lambda even: rage (e_get))
def rage(z):
    x = z
    img = image.load_img(x, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
    ...
```

`e_get` - поле ввода (см. выше по коду `e_get = Entry(root)`), вы его передаете в функцию `rage`, которая потом передает его в метод `load_img`.

Ищем документацию по методу `load_img`: [`tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img)

Видим, что первым аргументом должен быть путь к файлу изображения (`path: Path to image file`), но никак не поле ввода. Чтобы работало правильно, нужно прочитать из поля ввода текст (с помощью метода [`.get()`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) текстового поля), а потом уже передать его в `load_img`.

Можно поправить или в этой строке:

```
btn_start.bind('<Button-1>', lambda even: rage (e_get.get()))
```

тогда в функцию `rage` сразу будет передаваться текст из поля ввода. Или поправить саму функцию:

```
def rage(entry):
    image_path = entry.get()
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
    ...
```

Небольшой совет: старайтесь давать переменным (и функциям) осмысленные имена (не однобуквенные, не бессмысленные (что должна делать функция с именем `rage` ("ярость", "гнев")?)).